# Why does this Cyclic sort implementation have a bug?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Well known problem:

Given n number of array of range from 1 to n. Sort in-place O(1) space.

```
Input: [3, 1, 5, 4, 2]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

My solution was

```
  public static void sort(int[] nums) {
    int n = nums.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if(nums[nums[i] -1] != nums[i]){  // if I use while here it works.
        int j = nums[i] -1;
        int temp = nums[j];
        nums[j] = nums[i];
        nums[i] = temp;
      }
   }
 }
```

But this has a bug below.

```
Input: [1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2]
Wrong output: [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

If I use `while` (instead of `if`) in for loop, it works.
I don't understand why it has a bug if I use an `if` statement in the `for` loop.

Can someone please clarify why?

Comment: What language is your solution programmed in?

Comment: If you trace this with a debugger, what is the *first* point at which it behaved differently than you expected?

Comment: `Sort in-place O(1)` - This is the target (additional) _space_ complexity, not _time_ complexity. Execute your algorithm by hand.

Comment: Isn't this an odd problem anyway? You could generate the output while ignoring the input array, the only part you need is the length

Comment: Preston Guillot is right - changing to the "while" version of your algorithm will give O(1) space complexity (and, you know, work).  As for why it works, it's because you haven't necessarily gotten both swapped numbers to their correct places if you only check one time.  If you really wanted O(1) time complexity, I would think harold's suggestion is the only feasible way to do it.  But as he points out, why?

Comment: I never saw such strange algorithm and I do not understand how this should sort anything but by accident. But maybe it is just too late for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you don't want to do `Arrays.sort(nums)`

```
int[] nums= new int[]{ 1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2 }; 
int n = nums.length;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
    if (nums[i] < nums[j]) {
        int temp = nums[i];
        nums[i] = nums[j];
        nums[j] = temp;
    }
 }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  System.out.println(nums[i]);
}
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: the power of bubble sort

Comment: This isn't a cycle sort, this is a bubble sort. Both are O(n^2), but bubble sort does _way_ more swapping of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code with comments to note what is going on. Each swap puts at least one element into place. This is sorting by rank, since a[i]-1 equals the index it should be stored at. Space complexity is O(1). Time complexity is O(n).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int a[] = {3, 1, 5, 4, 2};
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
int i, j, t;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        while(i != (j = a[i]-1)){       /* while a[i] not in sorted position */
            t = a[j];                   /*  swap a[j], a[i] */
            a[j] = a[i];                /*   put a[i] into its sorted position */
            a[i] = t;                   /*   put a[j] into a[i] to be sorted later */
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%2d", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

This example code more closely follows the logic of a cycle sort. Rather than swapping elements, it uses a local variable to hold elements to be written later, so that every write stores an element into its sorted position, which minimizes the number of writes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int a[] = {3, 1, 5, 4, 2};
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
int e;                                  /* current element of a[] */
int f;                                  /* next    element of a[] */
int p;                                  /* sorted position for e */
int s;                                  /* start of cycle */
    for(s = 0; s < n; s++){             /* scan for cycles */
        e = a[s];                       /* get e */
        p = e-1;                        /* set p */
        if(p == s)                      /* if in place continue */
            continue;
        do{                             /* process a cycle */
            f = a[p];                   /*  get f (save a[p]) */
            a[p] = e;                   /*  put e into place */
            e = f;                      /*  update e */
            p = e-1;                    /*  update p */
        }while (p != s);                /*  repeat until end of cycle */
        a[p] = e;                       /*  put e into place */
    }
    for(s = 0; s < n; s++)
        printf("%2d", a[s]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```